# Detect index of lower case letters

Tags: python, string, lowercase

How do I get the index of all lower case letters of a string?

For example, the string `"AbCd"` would lead to `[1,3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple iteration over the string would do it:

```
s = "AbCd"
result = []
for i, a in enumerate(s):
    if a.islower():
        result.append(i)
```

Another way would be a list comprehension:

```
s = "AbCd"
result = [i for i, a in enumerate(s) if a.islower()]
```

Both cases result in the same:

```
result = [1,3]
```